# Two filters in Dash Table using callback function

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am wanting to filter the table according to selected date filter or dropdown or both. But I'm not able to integrate the two components to interact with the table. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

I don't know exactly how to put two filters to work on a single table

```
app.layout = html.Div([
    
    # Title
    html.Div([
        html.H1(children="test", id="title")
    ]),

    # Range Date
    html.Div(
        id="container_range_date",
        children=dcc.DatePickerRange(
            id="date_range",
            min_date_allowed=date(2016, 1 , 1),
            max_date_allowed=date(2021, 12, 31),
            initial_visible_month=date(2016, 1, 1),
            start_date=date(2026, 1, 1),
            end_date=date(2021, 12, 31)
        )
    ),

    # Menu Dropdown
    html.Div(
        id="container_col_select",
        children=dcc.Dropdown(
            id="col_select",
            options=[{"label":i, "value":i} for i in df["customer"].unique()],
            value=df["customer"][0:].unique(),
            multi=True,
            placeholder="customer"
        )
    ),    

    # Data Table
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id="table",
        columns=[{"name":x, "id":x} for x in df.columns],
        data=df.to_dict("rows"),
        fixed_rows={'headers':True},
        export_format="xlsx",
        filter_action="native"
    )
])

# Callback
@app.callback(
    Output("table", "data"),
    [Input("col_select", "value"),
    Input("date_range", "start_date"),
    Input("date_range", "end_date")]
)
def outputUpdate(dropdownValue, startDate, endDate):
    if type(dropdownValue) != str:
        dfFiltered = df[(df["customer"].isin(dropdownValue)) & (df["date"] >= startDate) & (df["date"] <= endDate)]
    else:
        dfFiltered = df[df["customer"] == dropdownValue]
    return dfFiltered.to_dict("rows")
```

Answer (score -1):

feel free to use this example and adjust it according your data model:

```
@app.callback(
    Output('table-container', 'data'),
    [Input('Filter1_dropwdown', 'value'),
     Input('Filter2_dropwdown', 'value')]
    )

def filter_df(filter_01, filter_02):
    if (not filter_01 and not filter_02):
        # Return all the rows on initial load
        return df.to_dict('records')


    filtered = df.query('filter_1_field in @filter_01 or filter_2_field in @filter_02')
    return filtered.to_dict('records')
```

Comment: I don't know if I was able to explain well what I need. I want to use a datepicker and dropdown together, but I'm not getting it.